# How to make formula based on rows in Ms.Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm looking excel formula that has the rows for the `if` variables.

```
      A       B
1     0      FALSE
2     1      TRUE
3     2      FALSE
4     0      FALSE
5     1      FALSE
```

I'd like to the cells in column B has `TRUE` text if only the cells in column A is `1 and 2 in sequence` and put the TRUE text in the beside the cell that has value of 1. Is this even possible in excel? I prefer not using makro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B1 write:

```
=IF(AND(A1=1,A2=2),TRUE,FALSE)
```

and drag it down the column
And will evaluate the sequence A1=1,A2=2 to True
and when you drag the formula it will increase the row, A2=1, A3=2...